# I need to log into apple mail to read new messages received from outlook

Tags: macos

I have a macbook Air and want to run outlook mail instead of using Apple mail. I have set up outlook as imap and it seems to be working fine, i can send and receive messages but for some reason I can't view them, they appear and then disappear instantly. I'm having to use Apple email to read my messages. I have tried syncing and everything I know, MS were useless. Do I need to remove Apple email? Can anyone advise please

Comment: Normally NOT, all you do is Quit Mail, and use Outlook. I would not uninstall mail since you might need it in the future. Why is Outlook misbehaving is another story.

Comment: The Outlook is forwarding emails to Mail.app, so stop that and Quit Mail.app

Comment: Are the messages still on the server? If not, remove the account from Apple mail as you're using the old pop3 method and that's why they don't show up in Outlook.

Comment: So i should remove my account entirely from apple mail?

Answer (score 1):

There is no interference with having more than one program retrieve IMAP mail.

Just quit Apple Mail and don't launch it while you work out whatever is not happy within Outlook.

Then your server will only see the requests from Outlook and you can focus on troubleshooting that setup. If you want to ask a second question on how to troubleshoot Outlook - just list your relevant details (version, etc) and document which troubleshooting article you are following from the Office support website (it's quite good in most instances) and you'll probable get some expert help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be helpful to get more details about your situation.

As far as I can guess :
You have an Outlook App
And you have Apple Mail.

OR :
You have an Outlook Account
And you have Apple Mail.

Apple Mail is just the software. And you can't delete it, because it is integrated in the System.

If you have an Outlook app and you are registered in Outlook Mail Services, then you just have to log in and everything should be fine. If your mails don't show up, it is more like a Software problem. So make sure the software is updated and (if you are running Mavericks) compatible with OS X Mavericks.

However, if you try to view your mails via Apple Mail and they don't show up, then it is indeed an error in the Settings or in the Software. 
In that case I would get the latest OS X updates and try again. If it doesnt work it is again an Outlook problem.

Comment: You **can** delete Mail.App, but you most likely do not want to do this as you need to force it via Terminal.

Comment: oh yes you of course delete it via Terminal, but for the normal user Mac OS X will tell you that it can not be deleted because it neccessary for the system.

Comment: Hi,Im using MS office on mac and outlook is part of the package.